# Compute child table values in formula field of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing a problem in Hibernate property formula field - I'm unable to combine both table columns.

`shift_id` column belongs to the parent table of `job_card` and `duration` column belongs to the child table of `job_card_idle_time`. But it considers both columns as belonging to the parent table of `job_card`.

```
<property
    name="utilization"
    formula="(count(shift_id)*340)-sum(duration)/(count(shift_id)*340)"
    generated="never"
    insert="false"
    update="false"
    type="float">
</property>
```

With the resulting query:

```
    select (count(this_.shift_id)*340)-sum(**this_.duration**) /(count(this_.shift_id)*340) as y0_,
    this_.JOB_CARD_DATE as y1_ 
    from job_card this_ 
    left outer join job_card_idle_time ir1_ on this_.JOB_CARD_ID=ir1_.JOB_CARD_ID 
    where this_.JOB_CARD_DATE between ? and ? 
    group by this_.JOB_CARD_DATE 
    order by this_.JOB_CARD_DATE desc
```

I want it as this.

```
    select (count(this_.shift_id)*340)-sum(**ir1_.duration**)
    /(count(this_.shift_id)*340) as y0_,
     this_.JOB_CARD_DATE as y1_ 
    from job_card this_ 
    left outer join job_card_idle_time ir1_ on this_.JOB_CARD_ID=ir1_.JOB_CARD_ID 
    where this_.JOB_CARD_DATE between ? and ? 
    group by this_.JOB_CARD_DATE 
    order by this_.JOB_CARD_DATE desc
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I suggest that you vote for answers that you find useful, using the up arrow next to the answer. And eventually, when one answer is correct for you, you might accept it by clicking on the little sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of query is best mapped as, well, query rather than derived property.

[Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property) can only contain SQL expression based on columns from **current** table. The only way to use columns from other tables is to write your formula as sub-select:

```
(SELECT count(card.shift_id) * 340 - sum(idleTime.duration) / (count(card.shift_id) * 340)
   FROM job_card card
   LEFT OUTER JOIN job_card_idle_time idleTime on card.job_card_id = idleTime.job_card_id
  WHERE card.shift_id = shift_id)
```

When you refer to column without an alias it will be prefixed with an alias of your main entity table during query execution. Note, however, that the above will not do what you want because you can't group within sub-select based on outside criteria. Also, depending on your database left outer join within sub-select may not be supported.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the precisions, I deleted my answer that proved useless.

Comment: "When you refer to column without an alias it will be prefixed with an alias of your main entity table during query execution." Is that still the case in hibernate 4.3.11? I have a simple formula where the parent entity _id is not being aliased:     `@Formula("(SELECT count(child._id) FROM Child child WHERE child._parent__id = _id)")` That last _id should reference the containing Entity (Parent), but it is never aliased in the generated sql.